# Can evaporated milk be converted to sweetened condensed?

Tags: substitutions, evaporated-milk, condensed-milk

(Not a duplicate of [**this question**](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/is-sweetened-condensed-milk-a-substitute-for-evaporated-milk), I don't believe)

If I have a recipe that calls for sweetened condensed milk but only have a can of evaporated milk, is there anything I can do to it to the evaporated milk to make it a suitable replacement for sweetened condensed milk?  Does the heating / sterilizing of evaporated milk ruin it as a replacement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may convert evaporated milk into condensed milk by adding sugar to it. For each cup of  evaporated milk [add about 1 and 1/4 cups of sugar](http://www.ochef.com/500.htm).  Pour the mixture in a pan, stir while heating on the stovetop until the sugar completely dissolves.  Let cool.  The heating of evaporated milk is similar to the treatment condensed milk undergoes, so the evaporated milk with sugar should be a perfect replacement.

Comment: Fabulous, I was hoping it was that easy :)  Cheers!

Comment: PSA: The link in this answer has rotted and was identified as a threat by Avast

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own sweetened condensed milk with the following instructions.
In a sauce pan place 3/4 cup white sugar mixed with 1/2 cup water and 1 1/8 cups dry powdered milk. Bring to a boil and cook, stirring frequently, until thickened, about 20 minutes.  You should get about 14oz from this.  If you, instead, would like to convert evaporated milk to sweetened condensed milk, follow the instruction above, from Papin.  Hope this helps.

Sincerely,
Ann

Comment: Can you substitute splenda for the sugar?

Answer (score -6):

I would add sugar and heat it up until dissolved.

Comment: This would be more helpful if you added specific details; note the quality of the answers that already exist.