# What is a good recipe that uses a lot of evaporated and/or sweetened milk?

Tags: culinary-uses, evaporated-milk

I have 60 oz of evaporated milk and don't know what to cook with it.  I have found some recipes, but they only call for 12 oz to be used and I'm about to get another 36 oz.  What is a good recipe (or recipes) that use a lot of evaporated milk?  Breakfast, lunch, dinner, snack, or desert recipes are welcome.  This [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/can-evaporated-milk-be-converted-to-sweetened-condensed) taught me that I can turn some of it into sweetened condensed milk, so that can be one of the ingrediants too.

Comment: Dear NoAlias, I am afraid that recipe requests are off-topic per [faq]. The "culinary-uses" clause is also limited to some very rare ingredients. This is why I vote to close. You can find such information in other places, such as recipe search engines. Feel free to come back with more specific questions about cooking, e.g. if you run into problems with a recipe you have found elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm, just reread your post; you probably need to change your question to something like; 'Have tons of evaporated milk, anybody know what I can do with it?'; otherwise it will likely be closed

Comment: This question does not currently meet any of our [guidelines for "culinary uses" questions](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/740/41). We welcome questions about using edible non-culinary or waste ingredients or other rare ingredients; common ingredients are better addressed by using an [ingredient-based recipe search](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12736/41).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flan, a type of custard, is the same as crème caramel, tasty desert.

Pumpkin pie uses a bunch of evaporated milk.

Ducle de leche is a terrific desert topping and filling, translated literally it means 'sweet of milk'.  The reason I mention this is that in Argentina and Chile, cans of sweetened condensed milk are boiled, unopened, on the stove for some hours to produce dulce de leche.  I understand that what you have is evaporated milk, which is different; there is no reason not to try using it to make this delicious treat.

Here is a link with a bazillion uses for evaporated milk:

http://www.carnationmilk.ca/recipes.aspx

Comment: Mmmm... flan... Oh, sorry, where was I?