# Can I use sweetened condensed milk instead of evaporated milk for pumpkin pie?

Tags: pie, pumpkin, evaporated-milk

The recipe calls for evaporated milk, but I only have sweetened condensed. Can I use it instead?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you just have to have an appropriate recipe. Google "[sweetened condensed milk pumpkin pie](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=sweetened+condensed+milk+pumpkin+pie)", you will find several recipes, including one by a major maker of sweetened condensed milk.

Comment: it is important to switch recipes, not just replace evaporated with sweetened condensed - it's thicker and sweeter and will make a different pie (see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/is-sweetened-condensed-milk-a-substitute-for-evaporated-milk ). The rest of the recipe has to be changed to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Take the 14 oz. can of condensed milk and and add 10 oz. of water. Wisk until mixed thoroughly. Using a couple of tablespoons less of sugar will result in an almost identical final pie.